# How can I find inside arrays using lowdb?

Tags: node.js

I'm using [typicode/lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) and I don't how to filter 3 attributes together, I'm getting brain freeze with this.

I have this json:

```
{"users": [
    {
         "accounts": [
             "1732011c-9748-4c02-8d04-6dfb457e848b"
         ],
         "blocked": false,
         "created_by": "email@email.com",
         "deleted_at": null,
         "id": "68c13cb0-a561-43c1-b304-355786a70d9b"
    }
]}
```

How can I find per those attributes: `blocked`, `deleted_at` and `accounts`? I don't know how to handle with this "accounts array"... If I use only `blocked` and `deleted_at`, I do:

```
db.get('users').find({ blocked, deleted_at }).value()
```

But how about `accounts` attribute that is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is straightforward.

```
db.get('users').find({ accounts:["1732011c-9748-4c02-8d04-6dfb457e848b"]}).value()
```

Comment: I can't believe it! I tried only without the array.. ty!